# How do you make a primary key with Valentina Studio?

Tags: mysql, valentina-studio

Creating a table with fields in Valentina Studio with a primary key 'id'.  How do you set a primary key with Valentina? I know how to in the terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you can by:

- Right click the table -> select 'Design'
- Click on the 'Constraints' tab in the dialog that opened
- Select the 'Primary Key' tab
- enjoy.